# download newest build of an artifact using maven in the command line

Tags: maven

All I want at the end of the day is for the puppet-managed servers in our development environment to always pull the latest build of the latest version of whatever application they are running. While maven isn't *exactly* intended for that, since all the shadowjars live in the same repository as their dependencies, and all come with md5 checksums to compare files that maven already generated, it seemed an obvious choice.

Trouble is, while I managed to pull the latest version through the command line, I have miserably failed in getting maven to check the pom.md5 to decide whether it needs to update a local jar or not. I tried some things with the dependency plugin, but when it already has a file with the same *version* locally, it just refuses to update it, even though the repository holds a newer *build* of that version.
So I've tried some things with the versions plugin, but again all I ever got are version numbers. I looked at the checksum plugin, but it seems dedicated to *generating* checksums. There's one check goal, but it requires some csv that I don't have, and I'm not sure how to get.

Really, all I want to do is for maven to compare the remote .jar.md5 with the local copy, and re-download the jar if they don't match, even if it's the same version. And I'd like to do it from the command line. But my hair is getting gray trying to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Maven is very efficient in dependency management. Thus is never re-downloads release jars.

**Option 1**

Make the version to be `SNAPSHOT`

**Option 2**
specify a version range

```
<version>[1.0,)</version>
```

At the end run

```
mvn -U -C clean package (or what ever you need)
```

Comment: That's just the issue, these *are* snapshots. The problem is not getting the newest version. That would be easy. The problem is getting the newest build of a snapshot version that is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call  using `mvn -U`, as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697970/598141).

The [Snapshots Update Download policy](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-settings/settings.html#snapshots) is controlled by a setting:

> `updatePolicy` String  The frequency for downloading updates - can be
> "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never"
> (only if it doesn't exist locally).

You can also use the command [`mvn maven-dependency-plugin:purge-local-repository`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html)   to do as it says, forcing a new download when you run [`mvn dependency:resolve`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html) or [lifecycle goal](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-reference) `generate-sources` or higher (ie: `compile`).